# docker -p solo funciona con el comando 'docker run' ? Porque cuando intento docker run -p 1234:80 da error (unknown shorthand flag: 'p' in -p)

Tags: docker

Estoy intentando arrancar un contenedor que ya existe. Uso `docker start nombre_contenedor` pero quiero que este vinculado a un puerto, entonces intento `docker start -p 1234:80 nombre_contenedor`  y me dice `unknown shorthand flag: 'p' in -p`. Entonces los puertos solo se pueden crear solo al arrancar por primera vez el contenedor ? es decir, con el `docker run nombre_contenedor`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El comando *start* no soporta el parámetro *-p*. Tienes que hacer un `docker run -p 1234:80 nombre_contenedor`.

El comando *start* es para arrancar el contenedor con las opciones que tenía cuando se paró el contenedor. Si quieres modificar esas opciones hay que utilizar *run*.

Saludos.

Comment: Vale perfecto, era entonces como sospechaba. Entonces a la minima de cambio de ports tiro un run y elimino el container anterior,no ?

Comment: No hace falta eliminar el contenedor anterior. A no ser que tengas que hacerlo por otro motivo. Lo paras y con run y el bindeo nuevo de puertos ya te arranca con esos puertos por defecto.